# I don't know how to fire up coqtail

Tags: coq, installation, vim

I installed coq and coqtail in my computer. According to this page:

https://github.com/whonore/Coqtail

Im now supposed to use the command

CoqStart

to launch the plugin. However, when I type ":CoqStart" the system responds: "E492: Not an editor command: CoqStart"

So, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error likely means either Coqtail wasn't installed correctly, it didn't load because of the file type, or it doesn't support your version of Vim/NeoVim.

To check for the first case, see if Coqtail is in your Vim runtime path (`:echo &rtp`). If not, double check that you didn't miss a step while installing with whatever package manager you're using (e.g., forgetting to do `:PlugInstall` with vim-plug). See https://github.com/whonore/Coqtail#installation-and-requirements for some options.

If it is installed, make sure the buffer you're editing has `filetype=coq`. This should be set automatically if you open a `.v` file, but you can also set it manually with `:set ft=coq`.

Finally, if everything is installed and you're editing a Coq file, check if `g:coqtail#supported` is `0`. Coqtail requires Python 3.6 or newer and it will fail to load and print an error if your Vim/NeoVim installation doesn't have it.

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason my Vim installation is defaulting ".v" files to "verilog" instead of coq. Once I changed the filetype, Coqtail launched correctly. I'll try to change it so that it defaults to the right file type.